# how to create imagestream of jbossweb in openshift origin

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

How can I create and use the imagestream of jboss webserver in openshift origin ?

Image yaml available in this [link](https://github.com/jboss-container-images/jboss-webserver-3-image). I see that it is automatically built with openshift enterprise version ([link](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/using_images/xpaas_images/jws.html)) . but why not in origin ?

Thanks.

I expected it to pull itself the image during build but did not happen.

```
D:\docker\apps>oc new-build --image-stream=jboss-webserver31-tomcat7-openshift:1.1 --name=newapp --binary=true
warning: Cannot find git. Ensure that it is installed and in your path. Git is required to work with git repositories.
error: unable to locate any images in image streams with name "jboss-webserver31-tomcat7-openshift:1.1"

The 'oc new-build' command will match arguments to the following types:

  1. Images tagged into image streams in the current project or the 'openshift' project
     - if you don't specify a tag, we'll add ':latest'
  2. Images in the Docker Hub, on remote registries, or on the local Docker engine
  3. Git repository URLs or local paths that point to Git repositories

--allow-missing-images can be used to force the use of an image that was not matched

See 'oc new-build -h' for examples.
```

So I tried to create the import yaml in webconsole but got below error with yaml.

```
Failed to process the resource.
Resource is missing kind field.
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Apparently one has to be logged in [redhat](https://access.redhat.com/containers/?tab=images&platform=openshift#/registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-webserver-3/webserver31-tomcat7-openshift)

```
oc import-image my-jboss-webserver-3/webserver31-tomcat7-openshift --from=registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-webserver-3/webserver31-tomcat7-openshift --confirm
```